# Is Simulink build something like .exe from our model?

Tags: matlab, compilation, simulink

In every model which are creating in Simulink are consist of some blocks and wires, I think blocks are shared library in the backend of Matlab, now I would like to know are those wires are shared library like blocks?
another question is:
 when we click on the play icon, we can see something in the taskbar which shows, compiling... my question is, Is at this phase Matlab building .exe file that containing those shared libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, it is compiling and than running the functions for each simulation step, see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/improving-simulation-performance-in-simulink.html). This is efficient since Simulink simulates multiple time steps of the same model and; therefore, it is worth invest a little time into compiling.
You can note the compiling if you use the Matlab-Code function block, where you need to activate code-generation. Nevertheless, you need the Code Generation Toolbox to divert the model as an .exe.

Comment: I would like to know where is the .dll that is specified for those wire.

Comment: I would like to know where is the location of the built model that is produced before running the Simulink model.